# Understanding a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an entity `Tag` and an entity `Note`. A `note` object can have several `tags`, and a `tag` object can have several `notes`. So say now I have a `Note` object `note1` and I have `tag` objects `tag1` and `tag2`. I add `note1` to the notes `set` in the `tag1` object. Then I also add `note1` to `tag2` object. My question is, is there only 1 instance of `note1` system wide? Or are there now two copies of `note1`, one for `tag1` and one for `tag2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there may or may not be more than 1 references to `note1` system-wide (you might have fetched the object somewhere else), but both `tag1` and `tag2` will have the *same* `note1` object (this is what you mean with same "instance", right?). The one that - if you've configured the relations correctly - will have two tags, namely `tag1` and `tag2`.